A movie/Tv series about a "dog toy" comes to life
I am looking for a movie I guess or a seriess Or was it a lifetime movie? I don't really know, I can only remember that it was an old movie so my only hope is to ask here I give a short summary from what I know;
There is a married couple the husband is a haunter and a little violent the wife is very cute very quiet, they have no children. She gets a gift from her sister, the gift was a dog toy to remember to her and her sister's earlier dog and everytime when the husband gets a little violent to his wife the dog toy comes "to life" and takes revenge.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Is there really nothing else you can add? Any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? What time was it likely from? What is "old"? What country was it likely from? Anything that might help identification? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

It's an episode of the twilight zone called "Acts of Terror". It came out in 1988. 


